# ui-route works just the first time angularJS

Tags: angularjs

i have a problems , after to have put the ui-route modal and page , i have another probleme my ui-route works just the first time and i don't know why

this is my route

```
  angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$qProvider){    
      $stateProvider

          .state("connexion", {
              url: "/",
               views: {

                // for column two, we'll define a separate controller
                'Principal': {

                    abstract :true,
                   templateUrl: 'connexion.html'

                }
               }

          })

          .state('agenda', {

            url: "/agenda",
            views: {

                // for column two, we'll define a separate controller
                'Principal': {

                    abstract :true,
                   // templateUrl: 'agenda.html'
                    template:'<a ui-sref="view">Open me!</a>'


                }
            }


        })
        .state('modal', {
        abstract: true,
        parent: 'agenda',
        url: '/modal',
        onEnter: ['$uibModal', '$state', function($uibModal, $state) {
            $uibModal.open({
            animation: true,
            ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
            ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
            resolve: {

            }
          })
        }]
      })
      .state('view', {
        url: ':id1',
        parent: 'modal',
        views: {
          'modal@': {
            template: '<div class="navbar">'+
                          '<div class="navbar-inner">'+
                          '<h4 class="brand">Quick Start</h4>'+
                          '<ul class="nav">'+
                          '<li><a ui-sref="foo">Route 1</a></li>'+
                          '<li><a ui-sref="bar">Route 2</a></li>'+
                          '</ul>'+
                          '</div>'+
                          '</div>'
          }
        }
      })
      .state('foo', {
        url: ':id2',
        parent: 'modal',
        views: {
          'modal@': {
            template: '<h1>foo</h1><a ui-sref="view">back menu</a>'
          }
        }
      })
      .state('bar', {
        url: ':id3',
        parent: 'modal',
        views: {
          'modal@': {
            template: '<h1>bar</h1><a ui-sref="view">back menu</a>'
          }
        }
      })

      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
       $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);

    })
```

and this a plunker,

http://plnkr.co/edit/4D6fsQv0FiPqtjoNiebS?p=preview

if some one can help me

thanks in advance

edit

Hello guys

**re edit**

```
.state('modal', {
        abstract: true,
        parent: 'agenda',
        url: '/modal',
        onEnter: ['$uibModal', '$state', function($uibModal, $state) {
          $state.go('view');
            $uibModal.open({
            animation: true,
            ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
            ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
            resolve: {

            }
          })
        }]
      })
```

Comment: seems like it continues to work fine in the plunker you provided;  what are you doing to make it stop?

Comment: when i close the modal window and i try to press again on open me , it s does nt work

Comment: because you are already on the `view` state, and closing the modal doesn't change to any other state.

Comment: Ok and how do I fix this problem? I tried to put a $ state.go ('view') in the modal route before opening the modal but I have the impression that there is an infinite loop check my edit